# Using SVN on Windows with Cygwin and TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, cygwin

I'm quite a beginner with version control so I might be doing something very wrong.

I want to be able to access a local repository both in cygwin and in TortoiseSVN (or other Windows app). The trouble is, in cygwin I have to use the
`file:///cygdrive/c/...` paths while TortoiseSVN needs
`file:///c:/...`.

How can I make these two work together? Can I use some other path/protocol that both understand?

Thanks!

Comment: @malenkiy_scot, the problem is, when I've created the repository in shell and then try to run tortoiseSVN repo browser on the folder, it throws an error `Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///cygdrive/c/...`.

Comment: Simply the path information in `.svn` folders is false for the windows system.

Comment: Well, the more I try to search the web the more it seems it's not possible to mix these two as even the svn processor is different (unix vs win)...

Comment: So your problem is not accessing the repository from cygwin and Tortoise, but rather sharing the same working copy.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot, I guess that would be the correct way of putting it.

Comment: BTW why do you even need / want to run the cygwin for Subversion?

Comment: @bahrep, because it's often useful to run commands from command line instead of GUI app like tortoiseSVN. And I use usually use cygwin because standard windows command line sucks. But currently I "fixed" it by using windows cmd.

Comment: He *might* be using the same working copy, but he is using the file:// protocol to access the repository through the file-system, not through a server. In that case, the format for specifying the file-system information is different between cygwin and "normal" windows apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy way is to use the `svnserve` program that comes with Subversion. This should be in Cygwin. All you need to do is start up the `svnserve` and use `svn://` as the protocol instead of `file://`.

First, you need to modify your repository. You'll have to edit two files: `svnserve.conf` and `passed`.

```
$ cd /cygdrive/c/.../repos_dir
$ cd conf
$ vi svnsever.conf   # Change the "# password-db = passwd" line & remove the "#"
$ vi passwd          # Setup the user and password entry
```

Next, you start the server:

```
$ cd ..    # Back to the repository directory
$ svnserve -r $PWD -d
```

And, that's it.

Now, you can do your checkout this way:

```
$ svn co svn://localhost/dir/to/check/out
```

This will be the same URL in both cygwin and in Tortoise

---

#### WORD 'O WARNING

There is no guarantee that different subversion clients will produce working directories that will work with other subversion clients.

Fortunately, Tortoise and the standard Subversion command line client seem to be okay. I've been able for the last few years to switch between the Subversion command line client and ToroiseSVN. **HOWEVER**, you do have to make sure that they're both ether post version 1.7 clients or pre 1.7 clients. If your Cygwin client is version 1.6.7 and your Tortoise client is 1.7.5, you can't share the working directory. Use the `svn version` command to check your Cygwin client, and check the *About Box* on Tortoise.

Again, there's no guarantee that both clients can share the same working directory, so if there are problems, you are on your own.

Comment: Thank you, David, I'll definitely take a look into it. In the meanwhile, I just used the subversion from windows command prompt which works well with Tortoise.

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way. Simply link the directory.

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c /C:
```

now it should work.

Credit goes to Mark Malaknov
You can read it here:

http://markmal.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-use-cygwin-svn-and-tortoisesvn.html

Answer (score 1):

If you (re-)install TortoiseSVN and select the option to install the (Windows) command-line tools, but *don't* install the Cygwin/Linux version of these tools from the Cygwin installer (or remove them), then your Windows tools will still be available via Cygwin.

These should accept Windows paths as if you were invoking them from the Command Prompt (although you might have to put them in quotes to avoid the bash shell from interpreting them)

Comment: Note: I've not tried this with a local repo myself; I prefer to run a local server as per David's suggestion - I usually just drop VisualSVN onto the windows box and set the repos up in that.